# When p-autocomplete is used inside p-accordion, space bar does not work on autocomplete. It toggles the accordion

Tags: angular, primeng

When p-autocomplete is used inside p-accordion, space bar does not work on autocomplete. It toggles the accordion. Need to ensure spacebar adds space in autocomplete.
Am using Angular 13 with prime ng 13

Comment: Please don't use incorrect tags. You are not using Java Server Faces / Jakarta Server Faces / JSF / PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can simply fix or workaround. It seems either a bug or simply not supported to me. You could try to add an issue at the PrimeNG issue tracker https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues.